# Remove SQL statement from output pane Datagrip

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagrip

In Datagrip, when you execute a statement you can get the output in the output pane.

I only want the resultrow to see, see my example below:

[image: The red part is what i don't want to see]

Red is the part i want to exclude, i only want the blue part.

Is there any way to do this?

I've looked on multiple websites, but I couldn't find an answer that fits my needs

Comment: Firstly, it's worth stating why you want to do this? I can't think of a good reason. Secondly, I've not used datagrip, but most database IDE's give you somewhere to write SQL, an option to execute, with the results shown in a new pane. I think this request is just going against the normal expected behaviour of a most modern SQL IDEs. An alternative solution would be to create a view that hides the SQL.

Comment: I want to do this because of multiple statements in different batches. I get all the sql query's in between what causes me to mannually search for the text i want to check. I don't see why this is relevant, i just want to hide it.

Comment: There is no such possibility now, but we agree it is important, so I've created a ticket in JetBrains DataGrip issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now:

There is no such possibility now, but we agree it is important, so I've created a ticket in JetBrains DataGrip issue tracker: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4384 – @moscas Mar 31 at 11:23